# htc one x screen wake up issue

Tags: screen, htc

I am having problem regarding my screen wake up. It wakes up from time to time automatically. I installed Wakelock Detector to track the app and found out Window manager has woken up the screen. I have formatted the phone but no luck.

Thanks